# Merging AJAX JSON call with dynatable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am a little new to JavaScript. I have a ajax request that gets my json data and places into a table and trying to integrate dynatable.js. However I am not sure best way to do this, as I need both.

Current JS:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    //global
    var current_file_index = 0;

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: 'server/php/',
        prependFiles:true
    }).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
        //data.formData = {date: data.files[0].date};
        data.formData = data.context.find(':input').serializeArray();
    });

    // Load existing files:
    $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');

    $.ajax({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $('#fileupload')[0],
        prependFiles:true,

    }).always(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
    }).done(function (result) {
        $(this).fileupload('option', 'done').call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
    });

});
```

Dynatable JS:

```
$('#remote').dynatable({
    dataset: {
        ajax: true,
        ajaxOnLoad: true,
        ajaxUrl: '/server/php/index.php',
        files: []
    }
});
```

If I use both those together I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>       at Records.count (jquery.dynatable.js:694)
>       at RecordsCount.create (jquery.dynatable.js:708)
>       at RecordsCount.attach (jquery.dynatable.js:734)
>       at RecordsCount.init (jquery.dynatable.js:704)
>       at Object.build (jquery.dynatable.js:186)
>       at Object.init (jquery.dynatable.js:142)
>       at HTMLTableElement. (jquery.dynatable.js:1673)
>       at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at n.fn.init.$.fn.dynatable (jquery.dynatable.js:1671)

If I do the following, kind of works but just adds the search, 0 out of 0 etc. I try to sort the table and removes all the data as it was loaded via the ajax. In a nut shell, I think I need to integrate them better so they work together.

```
$('#remote').dynatable();
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: And you're sure that you get a json response?

Comment: My JSON response when i go directly to the page is correct, and the ajax request loads it fine. https://anotepad.com/notes/6g4ich

Comment: Managed to work it out, will post solution in a moment

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting the solution for this please see below:

```
$.ajax({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    dataType: 'json',
    context: $('#fileupload')[0]

}).always(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
}).done(function (result) {
    $(this).fileupload('option', 'done').call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
    $('.table-striped').dynatable({
      dataset: {
        files: result,
        dataType: 'text'
      }
    });
});
```